# when inputing data from keyboard, how to complete input when user press "enter" in C++?

Tags: c++, cin

The problem is, in C++, I hope to get numbers from user and put every int to an vector. So I write the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> readVals()
{
    vector<int> read;
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    while (!cin.fail() && !cin.eof())
        {
            read.push_back(temp);
            cin >> temp;
        }
    return read;
}

void printVals(vector<int> v)
{
    if(v.size() >= 1)
        {
            for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++ )
        {
            cout << v[i] << " ";
            cout << v[v.size()-1] << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = readVals();
    printVals(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I compile it to create an a.out file. I have some numbers in `in1`. And when I do the command: `a.out < in1`, I got what I want.
But I'm confused when I hope the data can be inputted by user. The user can input some numbers and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to pass the numbers in. However, I used `getline()`, failed. `!="\n"`, failed. Everytime when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it seems that the program is still waiting for more numbers and not print out the result. Does any one can help me to make it successfully? Thank you!

Comment: Pay close attention to your `while` condition...

Comment: The input doesn't just end because you press Enter. That would indeed be a very terrible state of affairs.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is waiting for cin to be in a "failed" state or at the end of file. Hitting enter does neither. You can end the input by hitting CTRL-Z on windows or CTRL-D on unix/mac. These send the "End of file" character to cin. Alternatively, change your loop condition to "listen" for some specific input.

Comment: I try to use "getline()", but doesn't work. And I also try to use "when con =  "\n", break." but I don't know how to write it correctly. Could you suggest in which way or which function should I use to get what I want? Thank you!